# How to use external JavaScript functions in ReactJs component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use external js like jQuery, lighterjs and other js inside my react project.

I dont know how to include js inside my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iclude CDN link from [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) in your index.html in your root directory for react JS project. Then in your component you can use 'window.$'.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(window.$){
        window.$( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log( "ready!" );
        });
    }
}
```

So, you can use any JavaScript function right away with 'window.$' prefix.
Hope It will help...